# Transition Amplitude

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory

Question referring to this question
[Transition Amplitude in Free Field Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524996/)

The previous person shows an example with a two particle to one, what would happen if we were to get more particles out, like 3 or 4? Can you still call the state $a^{\dagger} _{k _{out}}$ for the out particles or would one need to have three/four ect individual out states to manipulate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The out state would be $\langle k_1^f \ldots k_n^f |= \langle 0 | a^\dagger_{k_1}\ldots a_ {k_n}^\dagger$, with $n$ number of particles in the **f**inal state.
You can convince yourself (invoking an argument like in the question you reference) that, in that context, inner products between states with different numbers of particle are zero.